# Reset product input quantity value once added to cart in WooCommerce

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

I would like to make sure that once a product has been added to the cart (both simple and variable), the selected quantity returns to 1.

For example I add a product with 5 of quantity in the cart, once added I would like to see 1 again as value in the product. Because quantity remains 5.

Starting situation

as you can see I have selected quantity 5 and click on add to cart.

and the product is added.

but the quantity remained at 5. I would like it to visually return to 1 here.

I try this code:

```
function insertcart_wc_loop_add_to_cart_scripts() {
 if ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product() ) : ?>

 <script>
 jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
 $("[name='quantity']").val(1);
  });
 });
</script>

<?php endif;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'insertcart_wc_loop_add_to_cart_scripts' );
```

Comment: Does your code works? what happen? Try to clarify your question. For normal add to cart this is not required as the page is reloaded/reseted…

Comment: So is it on ajax add to cart with a custom quantity field? Try to clarify your question and give more details on the customizations that you have already done yourself or via a plugin.

Comment: As you are using a custom quantity field and custom ajax add to cart on single product pages, nobody can really answer your question if you don't provide all the related customization code in your question. Note that *"The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem."***

Answer (score 1):

I am not a programmer, but I played around a bit with another code a found to set quantity steps and this works for me (finally):

```
/**
 * Reset quantity input add to cart
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 ); // Simple products

function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
        $args['input_value']    = 1;    // Starting value (we only want to affect product pages, not cart)
    }
    $args['min_value']  = 1;    // Minimum value
    $args['step']       = 1;    // Quantity steps
    return $args;
}
```